# Ensure multiple variable size flexbox divs stay inline?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some nested flexboxes of *a variable size* & **for each flexbox I'd like them to stay inline with the previous flexbox until the last possible beaking point** (E.g: fill all the line space with flexbox divs, as long as they can fit, without stretching/resizing the content!)

The "year" and "month" flex divs only seem to want to stay inline if their *entire content can fit*. I would prefer the flex divs to flow inline across the page regardless if they can fit their *entire* content. I'd like them to fit as much as they can (even if that's just a box or two).

Here's a photo to illustrate what I'd like the end result to be like: http://imgur.com/a/kN9w5

And here's a fiddle of the code so you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5q427Lgc/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="shelf">
        <div class="year"><span class="year-title">2015</span>
            <div class="month"><span class="month-title">March</span>
                <div class="album"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="month"><span class="month-title">February</span>
                <div class="album"></div>
                <div class="album"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="month"><span class="month-title">January</span>
                <div class="album"></div>
                <div class="album"></div>
                <div class="album"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="year"><span class="year-title">2014</span>
                <div class="month"><span class="month-title">December</span>
                    <div class="album"></div>
                    <div class="album"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="month"><span class="month-title">November</span>
                    <div class="album"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
<html>
```

And the CSS:

```
#shelf, .year, .month {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.album {
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    flex: auto;
}
.month-title, .year-title {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
    height: 17px;
    padding: 3px 2px 0 4px;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: The "year" and "month" flex divs only seem to want to stay inline if their entire content can fit. I would prefer the flex divs to flow inline regardless if they can fit their entire content or not. Is that any clearer?

Comment: So, you want part of the flex box on the same line and the rest of the flex box on the following line?

Comment: Bingo, Olaf. I can't figure out any way to do this!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

The flex children *do* stay on the same line, if possible. But they do so as a whole, they won't wrap sub-items to fit the remaining space.

If you want to achieve that, you must put the sub-items as direct children of the parent, e.g. not

```html
<div>year <div>month album album</div> <div>month album album</div></div>
```

but

```html
<div>year month album album month album album</div>
```

---

You might try a combination of `inline` (year, month) and `inline-block` (album) instead

```css
.year, .month {
    display: inline;
}
.album {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5q427Lgc/4/)

If you want to keep each year separate, use `inline` for `.month` only.

There's also a nice summary for `flexbox` at [CSS-Tricks - A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)